# Deleting very large list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, recycle-bin

We have a extremely large list, 237GB, that is sitting in the SharePoint recycle bin. The list was a result of a third party tool that was logging events. We were unaware it was doing this until we looked at the site's storage metrics.

I tried to delete it from the recycle bin in the evening but it never seemed to complete. I am concerned that when SharePoint tries to delete it after the retention period it will fail or cause performance issues. I'd rather plan for this to happen over a weekend where I can control it.

I am wondering if there is another way to get rid of this list that would be more efficient, such as powershell.

Thanks.

Comment: basically you want to empty the recylebin without taking sharepoint down?

Comment: I would prefer to delete only this one item if possible. We sometimes use the recycle bin as a first-stage recover tool when stuff gets deleted.

Comment: is it one item or thousands of items?

Comment: I looked at another smaller list from the same feature and it had 892,000 items so we could be looking in the millions :(

Comment: I have decided to put the list back in the site, write a script that deletes 50,000 items at a time (tested it and it takes about 1hr 20 mins), and set up a windows task to run the script every night. I might even have another script run over the weekend that deletes 100,000 items.

Comment: Yes that is the approach which we adopted in past. I was searching that script but looks like its gone from my pc...

Answer (score 0):

Per my comments, what I decided to do was to set up a task using windows task scheduler that runs a powershell script each night at 10PM. The script deletes 50,000 items and, according to the task start/end times, takes about 1.5 hours to complete. With 1 million items in the list it should take about a month to complete (since there are items being added daily). I have to put a ticket in with the feature vendor to find out how to stop the logging.

Below is the script I used. Although there may be more efficient methods, there is no hurry and this doesn't seem to tax the server it is running on:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -EA 0

$web = get-spweb https://sharepoint/site-collection
$list = $web.lists["list-name"]

$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true
$spQuery.RowLimit = 50000

$items = $list.GetItems($spQuery);

$items  | % {$list.GetItemById($_.Id).Delete()}
$web.Dispose()
```